# CakePhp Role and id restricted URL

Tags: cakephp

I'm learning CakePHP as I'm developing a new app.

I've setup user authentication and authorization on different pages.

What I need now is to setup a logic where a user can only edit/view his/her own page.

Right now the URls look like this:

http://domain.com/cakephp/users/view/3
http://domain.com/cakephp/users/edit/3

so if user goes in the location bar and changes 3 to 4, he can access and modify another user data. I must restrict that access.

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`isAuthorized`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) method from AuthComponent. Check documentation for more information. :)
Check AuthComponent 2.0 tutorials at YouTube from Andrew Perkins. They are great.

Comment: Thank you !those tutorials helped greatly :)

Comment: No problem. If you find this answer correct, please mark it. :)